# "Writefile" for RS232 communication using MFC hangs forever, but

Tags: c++, mfc, serial-port, writefile

I am maintaining a MFC program which can send data from computer A to computer B through RS232. Sometimes it transmits data smoothly, but sometimes it hangs forever. There are two threads sending the same data to a com port in sequence. The first thread sends data successfully, but the second thread hangs at the code "WriteFile". When the second thread on computer A hangs at "WriteFile", I send some meaningless data like "1" from computer B back to computer A. Then the hanging at "WriteFile" on computer A stop hanging, and computer B finally see the data sent by the second thread on computer A.

Here is the [RS232 log from computer B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88h3.png)
.

The picture shows that two threads on computer A initiate there own test and send messages back to computer B. Each thread complete there own test and send TEST_DONE to computer B almost at the same time. But computer B only see the TEST_DONE sent by first thread on computer A(The second thread is hanging at WriteFile at this point.) until I manually send "1" to computer A from computer B.

Here is my code sending message from computer A to computer B. The length of cmd is 255.

```
BOOL SerialPort::AutoHandlerRES(unsigned char* cmd){
while(wait_transfer.IsLocked())
    Sleep(1000);
wait_transfer.Lock(); 
CString out;
BOOL RetB;
UCHAR EndChar[2]={0x0D,0x0A};
out=CString(cmd);
DWORD num = out.GetLength()+2;
cmd[num-2]=EndChar[0];
cmd[num-1]=EndChar[1];
RetB=WriteFile(this->m_hCom, cmd, num, &num, NULL);
Sleep(1000);
wait_transfer.Unlock(); 
return RetB;}
```

My question is what could be the possible cause causing thread B hanging at "WriteFile"? Why the hanging does not happen on thread A? Thank you!

Comment: It's probably unrelated to your problem, but you're using the lock wrong. The point of `.Lock()` is to wait if the lock isn't open ; you don't have to wait yourself. The second sleep is also suspicious.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain the function well. The function will be called by many threads and all threads use the same RS232 com port handle. So I use lock to make sure a thread uses WriteFile at a time.

Comment: That doesn't change my point : you're using it wrong. There shouldn't be any while() nor Sleep().

Comment: Now I understand. ".Lock()" has both function that wait and see if the lock isn't open. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MSDN page about serial communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx) :

> If one thread is blocked waiting for its I/O operation to complete,
>   all other threads that subsequently call a communications API will be
>   blocked until the original operation completes. For instance, if one
>   thread were waiting for a ReadFile function to return, any other
>   thread that issued a WriteFile function would be blocked.

You probably issue a blocking `ReadFile` that prevent the `WriteFile` from completing. In your case it would be a race condition between threads ; the writes usually complete before the read is called, but not always.

The best way to prevent this would be to not call the `ReadFile` carelessly, but instead wrap it in the same lock as the writes, and wait on the receive COMM event before reading. The raw Win32 calls for that are `SetCommMask` and `WaitCommEvent`. You can then use `ClearCommError` to detect how many bytes should be read (because a receive event doesn't tell you how much data was received).

You can also use overlapped IO to allow simultaneous IO. I find it cleaner, but it's not simpler.

Comment: I should modify my code to check incoming RS232 data by checking COMM event, rather than read RS232 endlessly. Thank you very much!